# Confusion about that-clause and relative pronoun

Tags: word-order

"If I ever figure out an angle that I think would be useful to convey, I'll write it up" vs "If I ever figure out an angle I think that would be useful to convey, I'll write it up"? which is correct? Or are both incorrect? Why?

Another example: "I'm going to cite a comment [that] I think is in the same class" vs "I'm going to cite a comment I think [that] is in the same class". Which is correct or are both incorrect? Why?

Comment: Or you could just say "I'll write up any angle I think of that would be useful."

Comment: What research have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both cases, what the speaker thinks is the subordinate clause. Therefore, "I think" must be in the subordinate clause:

> If I ever figure out an angle [[that]] I think would be useful to convey, I'll write it up.

> I'm going to cite a comment [[that]] I think is in the same class.

Comment: what would be the subject of " would be useful" and " is in the same class"?  Why is it correct grammatically? I find it strange that there are no subjects before " would be useful" and " is in the same class"

Comment: @user43676856745 In both cases, the relative pronoun "that" is the subject. It's easier to identify if you omit "I think".

Comment: @MarclnManhattan so it is possible to attach two clauses after "that" : " I think", and " is in the same class"?

Comment: And is it wrong if I add one more that, like I'm going to cite a comment [that] I think [that] is in the same class?

Comment: @user43676856745 Yes, one clause is "embedded" in another. Look up "comment clause".

Comment: No, the comment clause does not get introduced by "that". Therefore the sentence should be: "I'm going to cite a comment [[that]] I think is in the same class." The comment clause is "I think". If you remove it, the sentence still makes sense.

Comment: thx, "[that] is in the same class" can be called an adjective clause and the main clause is "I'm going to cite a comment"?

Comment: @user43676856745 Yes, exactly!

Comment: @user43676856745 It's better to call it a relative clause.  Finite subordinate clauses are categorised by their internal form, not by spurious analogies with the parts of speech.    The main clause here is the whole sentence. "I'm going to cite a comment" is just part of the main (matrix) clause.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan "is in the same class" is a content clause embedded in the relative clause. Its subject is the relativised element, which has "comment" as antecedent. Not sure if you're saying that?

Comment: @BillJ I agree with everything in your first comment. As for your second comment, I don't recognize a content clause within the relative clause, and I don't know whether doing so would be useful for someone learning English at this level.

Comment: The relative clause is "(that) I think [ __ is in the same class]". Embedded within it is the bracketed content clause whose subject, represented by the gap __ notation, is "that", which has "comment" as antecedent. We understand that some comment is in the same class. This is an important point of grammar for students at any level.

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, I've assumed that "that" is a relative pronoun, which strictly speaking is not the case (it's actually a subordinator).

Comment: Oh yes, of course! I misunderstood. Please write that up as an answer, I think that that's also a good way of analyzing the sentence.